# Why should I use Angular 2? What are it's advantages over Angular 1?

Tags: angularjs, angular

Angular 1 excels in data binding and provided a structued MVC MVW framework.
It fails in providing built-in modularity.

What are the core selling points of Angular 2? Im not looking for opinion, just plain simple bullet point facts and Im only interested in core selling points.

Also what other libraries such as bootstrap / polymer gel well with angular 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me? Just off the top of my head:

- Support for Functional Reactive Programming using RxJS Observables.
- Built from the ground up with Typescript, meaning Types are a first class construct.
- Unidirectional data flow.
- Native ES6 Modules, no more endless script tags.
- Fully component based.
- Better template syntax.
- An even better Router.
- Much better Dependency Injection.
- Support for sped up initial loads thanks to server-side prerendering.
- ZoneJS Support, no more digest loop!

---

Of those my favorite feature is definitely the FRP support. We can drastically enhance performance by using Immutable Objects or Observables for our change detection.

The Formbuilder API as well as the HTTP API is fully compatible with `RxJS` making it very very powerful.

---

As for libraries, Angular-Material is obviously a big one. Another favorite of mine is NativeScript, which aims to create fully native mobile applications from your Angular 2 App. I'm sure there'll be tons more once it actually releases.

Comment: and don't forget the whole digest loop business  in Angular1 is gone

Comment: it always makes me cringe whenever I thing how Ang1 did 2 way data bindings